# Permission denied error while trying to uninstall Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, permission-denied

My computer: Mac Book Pro, OS X Yosemite

I am trying to uninstall anaconda with the following command.

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

However I get many many lines of Permission denied that looks like this

```
rm: /Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/__init__.py: Permission denied
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried with sudo?

Comment: @AustinKilduff  Thanks!! I just did : sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda and it worked.

Comment: In general, if you're using sudo with anaconda, you're doing something wrong.  It should be possible to do everything you need to do without sudo, and that prevents ownership issues like this one.

Comment: I am not quite sure what might have cause me not being able to uninstall it without the sudo and what I can do to prevent this from happening in the future. Your ideas would be appreciated. Best,

Answer (score 12):

On my OS X El Capitan,

```
sudo rm -rf //anaconda
```

worked. Note that @AustinKildoff already answered this question above.